# Boy and girl average scores

Tags: average, direct-sum

So I was doing an aptitude test when I stumbled on this question.

[image]
I can't make sense of it at all, does this kind of problem has a name I can research? How would you go about solving it?

I went as far as doing ->  (girl average score + boy average score)/2 which gives me $\frac{70+64}2 = 67$ and the problem says the whole class average is $66$, not $67$. I'm lost, if anyone has the kindness to explain to me how to work it out I'd be super grateful.

Thank you

Comment: Try the usual sort of thing.  Let $g$ be the number of girls, $b$ the number of boys.  So $g+b=60$.  Now, compute the total score accumulated by the class in two separate ways and compare.

Comment: To develop intuition for this kind of question, make up an imaginary class of 3 girls and 2 boys, make up some scores for each of the 5 students, then compute by hand the boys’ average, the girls’ average, and the class average. Try a bunch of different examples, changing the (keep it small) class size and the students’ scores. You will definitely discover that the class average score is not necessarily equal to (girls’ average score + boys’ average score)/2. (By the way, you might find help by looking up “weighted average,” which is what I might name the ideas here.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be solved without (much) Math, by using intuition.  What effect does the **overall** average have on each of the *gender* averages?

$(66)$ moves the girl's average of $(70)$ down by $(4)$ points, and moves the boy's average of $(64)$ up by $(2)$ points.  Therefore, the **weight** of the boy's average must be twice that of the **weight** of the girl's average.

So, you need to find two fractions, $a$ and $b$ such that $a + b = 1$ and $2a = b$.  This is *solved* by $~\displaystyle a = \frac{1}{3}, ~b = \frac{2}{3}.~$ Therefore, $~\displaystyle \frac{2}{3}~$ of the people are boys, and $~\displaystyle \frac{1}{3}~$ of the people are girls.

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe think of it as the solution to the following equation:
$$
64(x)+70(1-x)=66 \Leftrightarrow x = \frac{2}{3}
$$
Where $x$ is the percentage of boys in the class and thus $1-x$ being the percentage of girls.

And since you know the total number of students is 60 the number of boys in the class must be $\frac{2}{3}(60)=40$

Answer (score 0):

Let $b$ be the number of boys and $g$ be the number of girls.

Since the average of the boys is $64$, the total score of *all* the boys is $64b$, similarly, the total score of all the girls is $70g$. Now, we are given that there are $60$ students and the average is $66$. That means the total score of *all the students* is $60\cdot66=3960$. This gives us an equation:
$$64b+70g=3960.$$
Also, $b+g=60$. Solving this system of equations yields $g=20$ and $b=40$, hence the answer is B.

The average in this problem is *weighted* to the ratio of boys and girls. Since the number of boys is greater than the number of girls and they have a lower average, the class average of $66$ is lower than the average if the number of boys and girls were the same, which you found is $67$.